# Sql Php Ajax - Check if change in database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I currently have a ajax script to run a notiload.php file which runs every 5 seconds to check if theres a change in the database, if theres a change it then outputs "1 New" for a message. However as I will be introducing a notification sound in that file. It will chime every 5 secconds when the file is loaded. Of course this will piss people off. So I need the script to check if theres a change in the database. I have a time and date stamp of every message, with the message being viewed as 2 and not as 1. So if theres a change in the database I will need it to call that file or play a sound.

here is my ajax script inside the main page

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      refreshTable<?= $FriendName->id ?>();
    });

    function refreshTable<?= $FriendName->id ?>(){
        $('#NotiLoad<?=$FriendName->id?>').load('elements/notiload.php?id=<?=$FriendName->id?>', function(){
           setTimeout(refreshTable<?= $FriendName->id ?>, 5000);
        });
    }
</script>
```

```html
  <div id="NotiLoad<?= $FriendName->id ?>" style="display: inline-block;"></div>
```

And here is the php of notiload.php

```html
<?php
    session_start();

    // redirect to index page if not superuser  
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','');  
    if (!$con) {  
        die('Could not connect to Socialnetwk DB: ' . mysqli_error($con));  
    }
    mysqli_select_db($con,"ajax_demo");
?>
<?php
    $uid = $_GET['id'];
    $mid = $_SESSION['user']['id'];
?>
<?php $usrload = $con->query("SELECT * FROM message WHERE sender = $uid AND recipient = $mid AND seen = '2' OR sender = $mid AND recipient = $uid AND seen = '2'"); ?>
<?php while($FriendName = $usrload->fetch_object()): ?>
    <h6 style="display:inline-block;font-size: 10px;color:#37BC9B">1 New</h6>
<?php endwhile;?>
```

Comment: OK - what is your question?

Comment: Good point, to sum it up how would I check the database for any new message changes? Then set a notification off such as a mp3 file?

Comment: You could use an AJAX quest.

Comment: Do you know any resources that do the same or similar to what I need? I don't really want to go down the socket route, too complex for me right now